# matplotlib hatched fill_between without edges?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a region I'd like to hatch which borders on an existing plot line (of the same colour) that is dashed.

However, when I use `fill_between` the region to be hatched has a border drawn around it also. This border seems share properties with the lines that create the hatching so I cannot set edgecolour to "none" or set linestyle as "--" as the hatching is similarly affected.

```
import matplotlib.pyploy as plt
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],ls="--",c="b")
plt.fill_between([0,1],[0,1],color="none",hatch="X",edgecolor="b")
plt.show()
```

[image]

In this example I'd want the diagonal line from 0,0 to 1,1 to be dashed.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**>2.0.1 Update** As commented by @CatherineHolloway you need to use `facecolor` instead of `color` now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],ls="--",c="b")
plt.fill_between([0,1],[0,1], facecolor="none", hatch="X", edgecolor="b", linewidth=0.0)
plt.show()
```

---

**Former answer**

This seems to do the trick!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],ls="--",c="b")
plt.fill_between([0,1],[0,1], color="none", hatch="X", edgecolor="b", linewidth=0.0)
plt.show()
```

[image: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt]