# How do I fill a region with only hatch (no background colour) in matplotlib 2.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

With the recent updates to `matplotlib` `fill_between` and `hatch` ([see links here](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#new-in-matplotlib-2-0)), hatch filled regions are no longer behaving as they did previously. That is, the region is either filled with color, and hatches are black or the region isn't filled with color and hatches aren't visible.

Here is a side-by-side comparison of plots from the same code ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386106/matplotlib-hatched-fill-between-without-edges))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],ls="--",c="b")
plt.fill_between([0,1],[0,1], color="none", hatch="X", edgecolor="b", linewidth=0.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

is there a way to reproduce the 1.X plot in 2.X? I'm not at all familiar with back-ends but `mpl.rcParams['hatch.color'] = 'b'` and variations of the keywords `color, edgecolor` aren't helping.

Thanks in advance for helping to clear this up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### matplotlib > 2.0.1

*Since there was a lot of [discussion](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7901) on GitHub about hatching, there were now some changes introduced which make hatching much more intuitive.*

The example from the question now works again as expected, if the `facecolor` argument is used instead of the `color` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],ls="--",c="b")
plt.fill_between([0,1],[0,1], facecolor="none", hatch="X", edgecolor="b", linewidth=0.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### matplotlib 2.0.0

*To keep the original post, which has lead to this issue:*
In matplotlib 2.0.0 you can get the old style back by using `plt.style.use('classic')`.

```
##Classic!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = 'b'

plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],ls="--",c="b")
plt.fill_between([0,1],[0,1], color="none", hatch="X", edgecolor="b", linewidth=0.0)

plt.show()
```

Without setting the old style the following works by not setting the color to none, but instead make it transparent.

```
## New
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = 'b'

plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],ls="--",c="b")
plt.fill_between([0,1],[0,1], hatch="X", linewidth=0.0, alpha=0.0)

plt.show()
```

Both methods rely on setting the hatch-color via `plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = 'b'`.

Unfortunately, there is currently no other way of setting the hatch color in matplotlib  2.0.0.
The [matplotlib page that explains the changes](http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#hatching) states

> There is no API level control of the hatch color or linewidth.

There is an [issue on this topic](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7901) open at github and API control may be (re)added in an upcoming version *(which is indeed done with version 2.0.1)*.

Comment: Thanks! this does emulate the behaviour I was as asking for. Ideally, we could just use the `plt.fill_between`'s `color` argument to change the color of the hatching rather than `plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = 'b'` -- Allowing for simple use of multiple coloured hatches on the same plot. I'll hold off accepting the answer for now in the hope of such a solution

Comment: Updated the original answer with the changes that are now introduced with matplotlib version 2.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

With the release of matplotlib 2.0.1 [we now have much better control of the hatching](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/filled_step.html).

<s>Currently, the only way I can find to remove the background colour (as asked) is to set `color = None, alpha = 0` in the `fill_between` args. This works as requested but unfortunately results in pretty useless legends.</s>

Thanks to [QuLogic](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7901) pointing out I should be using `facecolor = 'none'` this now works perfectly.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plt_hist(axis, data, hatch, label):
    counts, edges = np.histogram(data, bins=int(len(data)**.5))
    edges = np.repeat(edges, 2)
    hist = np.hstack((0, np.repeat(counts, 2), 0))

    outline, = ax.plot(edges,hist,linewidth=1.3)        
    axis.fill_between(edges,hist,0,
                edgecolor=outline.get_color(), hatch = hatch, label=label, 
                facecolor = 'none')  ## < removes facecolor
    axis.set_ylim(0, None, auto = True)

h1 = '//'
d1 = np.random.rand(130)
lab1 = 'Rand1'
h2 = '\\\\'
d2 = np.random.rand(200)
lab2 = 'Rand2'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

plt_hist(ax,d1,h1,lab1)
plt_hist(ax,d2,h2,lab2)
ax.legend()
```

[image: example plot]