# The shaded area derived from fill_between has a white border

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted some training curves where the shaded area represents the standard error. The shaded area is realized with the `fill_between` method in `Matplotlib`. However, the derived `.eps` figure showed that the shaded areas have white borders, which can be observed in the below figure.

How can I remove these borders or set the `edgecolor` to the same as the `facecolor` and change its opacity?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386106/matplotlib-hatched-fill-between-without-edges) only changes the `edgecolor`'s opacity.

[image]

I have changed the `edgecolor` via `edgecolor=face` but got solid line borders. Changing `alpha` of `edgecolor=(R,G,B,alpha)` seems useless to me. I want to further adjust the opacity of `edgecolor`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds similar to the problem [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263769/hide-contour-linestroke-on-pyplot-contourf-to-get-only-fills) where edges show up in saved PDFs. I can't test this without some example code of your problem, but if you can access the artists drawn onto the axis by fill between and set their `edgecolor="face"` then this may solve your issue.

Update: As mentioned in the comments below, it is additionally necessary to set the linewidth as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386106/matplotlib-hatched-fill-between-without-edges)

Comment: Thanks for your help. `edgecolor="face"` does eliminate the white border and sets the same color as `facecolor`, but there will be solid lines. I have tried to changed the opacity through RGBA of edgecolor but failed. How can I change the opacity of `edgecolor`? Thanks.

Comment: I have found a way to change the opacity of `edgecolor` via `linewidth`. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386106/matplotlib-hatched-fill-between-without-edges. Hope you can edit your answer and I have accepted it.