# matplotlib: combining hatching with pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
colors = ['darkgreen', 'darkred', 'red', 'green', 'lightgray']
to_plot = np.swapaxes(all_channel_maps, 0, 1)
# to_plot = all_channel_maps
plt.pcolormesh(to_plot, edgecolors='k', linewidth=0.1, cmap=ListedColormap(colors))
ax = plt.gca()
# ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
print(ax.pcolor)
plt.show()
```

`all_channel_maps` is a 2D array of integers ranging from 0 to 4, each mapped to a specific color.

I want the cells with dark colors (values 0 and 1 in `all_channel_maps`) to be hatched in the resulting image.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show whar your plot currently looks like and maybe a drawing of what you'd like it to look like? Also, it would be helpful if you provided some test data to plot.

Comment: I don't see any `fill` or [fill_between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386106/matplotlib-hatched-fill-between-without-edges) to put [hatching](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_style_reference.html) in your figure.

Answer (score 3):

## Hatching via `pcolor`

`pcolormesh` doesn't seem to do hatching. But the very similar `pcolor` does.

The following code first draws the original `pcolormesh`, and then on top `pcolor` with hatching.  Using a ListedColormap with 'none' as only color, doesn't disturb the coloring (including edges) of the `pcolormesh` and lets you specify a different color for the hatching. (Hatching uses the edgecolor.)
Masking makes sure only the cells that comply with the condition are hatched.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

colors = ['darkgreen', 'darkred', 'red', 'green', 'lightgray']
to_plot = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(5, 8))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4))

ax.pcolormesh(to_plot, edgecolors='black', linewidth=0.1, cmap=ListedColormap(colors))

ax.pcolor(np.ma.array(to_plot, mask=to_plot > 1), cmap=ListedColormap(['none']),
          hatch='xx', edgecolors='yellow', linewidth=0)

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: combining pcolormesh and hatching]

## Hatching via `fill_between`

Another approach would draw the `pcolormesh` twice. Once the cells that need hatching. Then `fill_between` with hatching over the complete image. Finally, on top the cells that should go without hatching.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

colors = ['crimson', 'limegreen', 'crimson', 'limegreen', 'lightgray']
to_plot = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(5, 8))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4))
kws = {'edgecolors': 'blue', 'linewidth': 2, 'vmin': -0.5, 'vmax': len(colors) - 0.5,
       'cmap': ListedColormap(colors), 'clip_on': False}
ax.pcolormesh(np.ma.array(to_plot, mask=to_plot > 1), **kws)
ax.fill_between(ax.get_xlim(), *ax.get_ylim(), color='none', edgecolor='steelblue', lw=0, hatch='+++')
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(np.ma.array(to_plot, mask=to_plot <= 1), **kws)
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)  # hide the surrounding spines
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xticks([])  # remove x ticks
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image: hatching a pcolormesh via ax.fill_between]